# Выбор нескольких классов getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть `div` с классами `text и clicked`

```js
var borderw = document.getElementsByClassName('text clicked');
    function borderWidth() {
      borderw.style.borderWidth = "10px";
    }
```

```css
.text.clicked {
  border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="text clicked">XXX</div>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="borderWidth();" >Click</button>
```

Как выбрать через `getElementsByClassName()` сразу два класса? Нужен для css, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку добавлялся `border-width`.

Пытался так сделать, ошибки не могу найти.

Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем два класса? Одного может быть достаточно. Еще нужно событие при котором сработает функция. Типа onclick или onload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте лучше `document.querySelectorAll`

```js
const borderw = document.querySelectorAll('.text.clicked');
const button = document.querySelector('button'); // вернет только один элемент!

// querySelectorAll вернет коллецию, не настоящий массив!
// поэтому с помощью [...] превращаем его в настоящий массив
function borderWidth() {
  // так как borderw массив, то что бы стили сработали
  // нужно в цикле пройтись по каждому элементу и ему присвоить стили
  [...borderw].forEach(el => el.style.borderWidth = "10px");
}

button.addEventListener('click', borderWidth);
```

```css
div {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text clicked">XXX</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а через onclick="borderWidth(); как использовать? Вопрос чуток отредактировал

Comment: @АндрейЗахаров обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вполне можно обойтись одним `КЛАССОМ`, это во-первых.
Во-вторых любую функцию надо запускать, в данном случае реализовано нажатием на сам блок. И последнее, элементов с `КЛАССОМ` может быть куча, или надо указать индекс или прокручивать в цикле

```js
var borderw = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0];

borderw.addEventListener('click', function borderWidth() {
  borderw.style.borderWidth = "10px";
})
```

```css
.text {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text clicked">XXX</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию элементов

```js
var borderw = document.getElementsByClassName('text clicked');

for(var i = 0; i < borderw.length; i++){
 borderw[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.style.borderWidth = "10px";
 }); 
}
```

```css
.text{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text clicked">XXX</div>
<div class="text clicked">XXX</div>
```